# Github Pages does not load the three.js animation

Tags: javascript, github, three.js, github-pages-deploy-action

My index.html runs well when i when i do '''parcel index.html''' locally, but when i posted it to github pages, it does not shows the js animation. And i see the console of the browser, it doesn't shows any error, what should i do to make the image animation show up? (I am pretty new to this, thanks for the help)
Here is my website link.
https://mollyxuemn.github.io/Meini-sWeb/
It should be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG6FM.png)

For the code please see: https://github.com/MollyXuemn/Meini-sWeb

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is the `gsap` import here: https://github.com/MollyXuemn/Meini-sWeb/blob/a6a4b36ece3c52bd2dcfd73ae6b276b3f8dec8e7/app.js#L2

The same app.js is loaded on the website: https://mollyxuemn.github.io/Meini-sWeb/app.js but you should load a compiled/bundled js file instead I believe, which includes your dependencies as well.

Comment: https://github.com/MollyXuemn/Meini-sWeb/tree/main/dist,here i do bundle everything, but the animation still doesn't works, can not figure it out .

Comment: On the site you still import https://mollyxuemn.github.io/Meini-sWeb/app.js which is a non-compiled javascript file, and the browser can't do anything with it. You should import your resources from the dist directory on production, if you have your compiled and bundled resources there.